# Pagination of files using Google Drive api client library

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to paginate the `Google Drive` files using `Google Drive` API client library.

I'm using Google Drive Service account with ASP.Net C#. To populate the uploaded files I'm using the following code-

```
FilesResource.ListRequest list = service.Files.List();
list.MaxResults = 1000;
if (search != null)
{
   list.Q = search;
}

FileList filesFeed = list.Execute();
foreach (File item in filesFeed.Items)
{
  // loop the files
}
```

Suppose there are 100 files in my account.

How could I paginate the files like 10 records for each page?

Answer (score 3):

You need to basically add the NextPageToken to your subsequent requests.
Use

> request.PageToken

to set the NextPageToken recieved in your first request.
Following would be a code example for subsequent requests.

```
FilesResource.ListRequest request = service.Files.List();
request.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";
request.PageSize = 1000;
request.OrderBy = "modifiedTime";
FileList response = request.Execute();
while (true) {
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.NextPageToken)){
    request = service.Files.List();
    request.PageSize = 1000;
    request.OrderBy = "modifiedTime";
    request.PageToken = response.NextPageToken;
    request.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";
    request.Q = "trashed = false";
    response = request.Execute();
  }
else{
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using PageStreamer here is an example using the Drive API V2.

```
 var pageStreamer = new PageStreamer<Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File, FilesResource.ListRequest, FileList, string>(
                                                   (request, token) => request.PageToken = token,
                                                   response => response.NextPageToken,
                                                   response => response.Items);

 var req = service.Files.List();
 req.MaxResults = 1000;


foreach (var result in pageStreamer.Fetch(req))
  {
  Console.WriteLine(result.Id);
   }
```

Comment: @DaImTo...The PageStreamer is not working with Google.Apis.Drive.v2. I'm very much stucked with the google drive files pagination issue

Comment: Updated it for Drive V2

Comment: @DaImTo How do you get PageStreamer for Google Drive api V2? I m not able to find the reference to it.

Comment: This is the code you should use. It's part of the Google APIs dotnet client library

Comment: @DaImTo I use the above code and I get the following compiler error: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'resource extractor' of 'PageStreamer<File, FilesResource.ListRequest, FileList, string>.PageStreamer(Action<FilesResource.ListRequest, string>, Func<FileList, string>, Func<FileList, IEnumerable<File>>)'

Comment: Log it as an issue maybe one of the other will have time to check it out i won't have time for a few weeks https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve pagination though 'nextPageToken'. Here I am trying to explain your scenario with sample code. The code(using Java REST API v3) is for getting 6th page from total 10 pages, each contains 10 files.

```
public static FileList getPage(Drive service, int pageNumber, int pageSize) throws IOException {

    private static final int DRIVE_MAX_ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 1000;
    int skipCount = pageSize * (pageNumber - 1);

    // Skipping previous pages by requesting only next page token for light weight responce.
    Drive.Files.List list = service.files().list().setFields("nextPageToken");
    while (skipCount > 0) {
        int pageSize = 0;
        if (skipCount > DRIVE_MAX_ITEMS_PER_PAGE) {
            pageSize = DRIVE_MAX_ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
            skipCount -= DRIVE_MAX_ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
        } else {
            pageSize = skipCount;
        }
        FileList result = list.setPageSize(pageSize).execute();
        if (result.getNextPageToken() == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "getPage Failed: Google drive does't have requested page.");
        }
        list.setPageToken(result.getNextPageToken());
    }

    // Returning requested page.
    return list.setQ(query).setFields("*").setPageSize(pageSize).execute();
}
```

Hope this is useful for you .....

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I couldn't convert some coding lines in c#. Like FileList result = list.setPageSize(pageSize).execute(); The "setPageSize" property is not supporting. I'm using Google.Apis.Drive.v2  So the paging issue is still pending

Comment: The question is about C# and the .net client library why would you post an example in Java?

Comment: I just tried to give him an approach for the solution.